# matlab code to prompt a user for input inside a loop

Tags: matlab, mean

I  was asked to write a matlab code to calculate the mean of 5 numbers utilizing a loop structure, I wrote this code but I was wondering if I could do something to make matlab ask me to enter the values in order 1 to 5,  for example " Enter Value 1 " " Enter Value 2" ,  etc.

```
sumx = 0;
N = 5;
i=1;
for n =1:N
i=i+1;
Valuei=input('Enter Values= '); 
sumx = sumx+Valuei;
end
Ybar=sumx/5;
display(Ybar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
N = 5;
for n = 1:N
   prompt = sprintf('Enter Value %d=', n);
   Value = input(prompt);
   ...
end
```

The `%d` is replaced by the value of `n` for each iteration of the loop.

Also, the variable `i` isn't used. You can get rid of it. It's a bad idea to use `i` (or `j`) as a variable name anyway since it's already defined by Matlab to be the imaginary unit.